# instance of class in python (fundamental explanation)

Tags: python

When I create some class in python:

```
class Someclass():
   def __init__(self, some_arg):
       self.arg = some_arg
```

Then I create an instance of this class:

```
>>> some_instance = Someclass('something')
```

Then the output about our instance:

```
>>> some_instance
>>> <__main__.Someclass instance at 0x00000000021CA848>
```

Now I have few questions:

1) What does `__main__` mean exactly in this example?

2) What does `**at 0x00000000021CA848**` mean, and what do I need this information for?

Comment: You need this information for debugging. When two variables, when printed, show the same address (hex number), you can assume they reference the same instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`__main__` is the module's name and `0x00000000021CA848` is the address of the object in memory, if you are using CPython.

Its the string representation of your object. You can use it for debugging.